# Returning an invalid point

Tags: c#

I have a self-defined class of `myPoint`

```
class myPoint
{
    double X,Y;
}
```

Sometimes I might want to return `myPoint` from a function that indicates that it is an invalid solution, rather than `(0,0)`.

In this case, how do I define `myPoint` class such that it has an invalid field. And how do I go about checking this condition?

Comment: You personally must decide what means invalid point in terms of business logic. If your point cannot have negative coordinates, then (-1,-1) may be a good option. Also, you can consider throwing exception instead of returning invalid point.

Comment: You can do it in whichever way you'd like. You can return (-1, -1), Or you can return a `null` instance.

Comment: you can add an Bool attribute which indicated if the point is vailt or not

Comment: That is entirely up to you...

Comment: Show the method that might return an "invalid" response and show how  you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double` has a special value, `double.NaN` that isn't a number ("Not a Number"). You check it with `double.IsNaN(someNumber)`. It has the advantage that it self-propagates, so that `double.NaN + 1.0` is `double.NaN`. Note that you **must** use `double.IsNaN()`, because `double.NaN == double.NaN` is `false`.